# Nodemailer: How to get a response of fail to send?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to make an email system by nodemailer.

And it always works in spite of a wrong recipient address.

my mailOption is:

```
const mailOptions = {
  from: "sender@mydomain.com", // Sender address
  to: "receiver@example.com", // List of recipients
  subject: "Node Mailer", // Subject line
  text: "Here's a text version of the email.",
  html: `<h2 style="color:#ff6600;">Hello People!, Welcome to Bacancy!</h2>`,
};
```

I got the response:

```
{
  accepted: [ '******' ],
  rejected: [],
  envelopeTime: 97,
  messageTime: 211,
  messageSize: 664,
  response: '250 2.0.0 OK <******> [Hostname=*******]',
  envelope: { from: '*******', to: [ '******' ] },
  messageId: '<*******>'
}
```

**How do I get a response when sending failure due to recipient address wrong?**

My code is:

```
let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.office365.com",
  port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: "*******",
    pass: "*******",
  },
  secure: false
});


transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(info);
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.pending);
  }
  transport.close();
});
```

I know the 'err' in 'transport.sendMail()' is for when the email system errors.

And I expect that I can get a return/responce as well when the recipient is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That's not so much the job of Nodemailer, rather the service provider. Which one are you using and do they provide a response on failure to reach an inexistant recipient would be questions you ask for before buying the service.

Comment: I use Microsoft365, and it really has a response, because I can receive the email from the provider. Even so, should Nodemailer provide a function/method/attribute to listen to the response?

Comment: Could you provide more info on how you tested the provider, also, what's the content of mailOptions object; sendEmail should return an expressive error in it's callback method, so if your provider is sending down the "Non-existing recipient" error, you're going probably to seen it in your error or response objects (depending on whether Nodemailer interprets your providers response as either a straight error or just a normal response).